# switch fall through being ignored by JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm running my code through [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), and I'm hitting this error:

> Expected a `break` statement before `case`

On this block of code:

```
switch(true)
{
    // Renames skill1=abc to section_8_1_body=abc
    case Major === 0 && Minor === 0 && Patch < 433:
        upgraded = upgraded.replace(/(\s+)skill(\d)=/gm, '$1section_8_$2_body=');
    /*falls through*/

    // Example
    case Major === 0 && Minor === 0 && Patch < 442:
        console.log('test');
    /*falls through*/
}
```

The code checks version information for a file, and upgrades it to be compatible with the latest version of the software. It's therefore intentional for the `case`s to fall through, so that a file can be upgraded through multiple versions.

However, I still receive the error message, *with* `/*falls through*` added, even though [it is supposedly valid](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/18).

How can I allow my `case`s to fall through successfully in JSHint?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JSHint seems to expect the comment to be on the line right before the `case`.

```
// Example
/* falls through */
case Major === 0 && Minor === 0 && Patch < 442:
    console.log('test');
```

According to the description [in the source code](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/adbaf51bcbcc96fc58cf4ea78476225e8dba92c5/src/jshint.js#L3604-L3609), it won't acknowledge the comment otherwise:

```
// You can tell JSHint that you don't use break intentionally by
// adding a comment /* falls through */ on a line just before
// the next `case`.
```

Comment: Ah, thanks Jonathan! I tried removing the `// Example` line but I still hit the same error. The problem was the blank line between `/*falls through*/` and `case`.