# jshint throws a"Expected a 'break' statement before 'case'"

Tags: javascript, jshint

Hi I am having a trouble when my framework is using jshint to validate my `javascript` code. I have used switch-case without a break statement intentionally, but this portion of code is captured as an error when `jshint` checks. My code is something like below.

```
    switch (<no>){
    case 1:
        // does something
    case 2:
        //does something more
    default:
        // does something even more
   }
```

`Error from 'jshint' is like Line 203 character 41: Expected a 'break' statement before 'case'.`
Any thoughts on how to avoid it ? or is it a bad practice to use switch cases in this scenario at all ?

Comment: What's the real world case? Why don't you need `break`?

Comment: When the case 2 hits , I need case 2 & all below should get executed. It is true for all the cases. Something of that sort.  My logic works fine, but the validation fails.

Comment: I often have switches where I don't really need `break` in every case, that's not too uncommon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [switch fall through being ignored by JSHint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015612/switch-fall-through-being-ignored-by-jshint)

Comment: If you're just doing a fall-through it should be ok, but maybe there's a better alternative, posting your real code would help. A dictionary lookup is a common alternative.

Comment: The same thing happens when I have a rather complex statement with a `return` statement somewhere in the `switch` (e. g. a nested switch). I haven’t used `break` because it seemed redundant.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Copy & paste [from the documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/):

> Switch statements
>
> By default JSHint warns when you omit break or return statements within switch statements:
>
> [...]
>
> If you really know what you're doing you can tell JSHint that you
>   intended the case block to fall through by adding a `/* falls through */` comment

So in your case:

```
switch (<no>) {
  case 1:
    // does something
    /* falls through */
  case 2:
    //does something more
    /* falls through */
  default:
    // does something even more
}
```

Comment: Thanks for just giving him the answer without all the back and forth grilling the guy about why he wants to do this  :)

Comment: +1.  by design, switch statements support breaks, or no breaks, depending on the behavior you need.  Otherwise, why would languages require you to add a "break" at all

Answer (score -1):

Exactly, `break`s may be totally superfluous, like in this example

```
function mapX(x){
  switch (x){
    case 1:
      return A;
    case 2:
      return B;
    default:
      return C;
  }
}
```

In this case, if you would have had a `break` after `return`, [JS Standard](https://standardjs.com/) would throw a warning, namely `Unreachable code`.

Trying to conciliate jshint and JS Standard is tricky, but as stated, the solution would be

```
function mapX(x){
  switch (x){
    case 1:
      return A;
      /* falls through */
    case 2:
      return B;
      /* falls through */
    default:
      return C;
  }
}
```